# how run laravel php artisan websocket:init command on online server?

Tags: laravel, websocket, server

i run websocket on **localhost** in laravel with this command:

```
php artisan websocket:init
```

and It works properly.
but i use cpanel in online server. and i dont access to terminal. how run websocket on online server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont, you need to have ssh access to the server to run the command. You can try schedule to run the command but I'm almost 99% sure that won't work. I talked with my hosting company if I could run a simple cache clear and they said I had to pay for ssh access.